# javascript random number looking for hasClass that doesn't exsist

Tags: javascript, jquery

To make this fairly simple my comments in the code say what I'm trying to accomplish.  My code when executed seems to not continue to calculate until it finds an .wrap with an empty class, which is what I'm trying to do.  Maybe someone can help me figure out how to extend the infinite checking to eventually find an open .wrap which the class has not been defined.

```
function computerMove(){
    //returns number between 1-9
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    console.log(rand);

    //checks for if .wrap has class of x and if it does it should get another number
    var check = $(".board .wrap:nth-child("+rand+")").hasClass("x");


    if(check){
    console.log("checking") 
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1); 
    //I believe this should work and repeat the function
    computerMove();
    }
    else{
    $(".board .wrap:nth-child("+rand+")").addClass("o");
}
```

Comment: Are you running this within a loop or is this all the code?

Comment: @NickKenens it's recursive function.

Comment: @jcubic I noticed it after typing, my bad. Is there any benefit to using recursive function over looping if there are no arguments given? Just seems kinda wild to me.

Comment: Shouldn't you check for class `o` too? or it doesn't matter to pick an element with that class twice

Comment: It's just asking for trouble to write this as a recursive function.

Comment: `it finds an .wrap with an empty class` What do you mean by empty class?$  You chould provide MCVE to make your question clearer i think

Comment: You guys are probably right it should be a loop instead of recursive, I should look for if it has x or is empty and then add o as the class.  I don't want x and o to be on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use recursive function when you don't have to. Use loop.

```
function computerMove(){
    var check;
    var rand;
    do {
        //returns number between 1-9
        rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
        console.log(rand);
        check = $(".board .wrap:nth-child("+rand+")").hasClass("x");
    } while (check)

    $(".board .wrap:nth-child("+rand+")").addClass("o");
}
```

Or it could be simpler to "smartly" use jQuery selector

```
// Find all elements that do not have x class
var items = $(".board .wrap:not(.x)")
// Get a random element
var target = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
// Add o class to the target
$(target).addClass('o')
```